# What is the correct path and directory format for .ebextensions/static-files.config

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble deploying my app. I have static files at public/javascripts and public/stylesheets. What is the correct way to write that in the static-files.config file for AWS Elastic Beanstalk...

This doesn't work...

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /public/javascripts: javascripts
    /public/stylesheets: stylesheets
```

It is a Mongo, Express, Node app using EJS.

The problem in more detail is this...when the app deploys, my home page is there with no styling and none of the links work. I have rearranged the ordering of things in the config files several ways but nothing seems to help get the app to see the stylings and javascript. One version had the file like this...

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /javascripts: public/javascripts
    /stylesheets: public/stylesheets 

                                                                                                  and I ended up with this error in the log...
```

---

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

2022/02/14 18:05:08 [error] 3601#3601: *13 open() "/var/app/current/stylesheets/.env" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 20.97.246.144, server: , request: "GET /public/.env HTTP/1.1", host: "3.98.252.66"

In the app structure, the public folder is at the root/top level with the javascripts and stylesheets folders the next level down from public(in otherwords /public/javascript/ and /public/styleshhets/). The javascript folder contains three javascript files, and the stylesheets folder contains three css files. If I knew for sure the config was correct, I could move on to see if the problem is something else. The app of course works in development and when deployed to Heroku.

This is the documentation from AWS...
[AWS elastic beanstalk static files documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html)

K

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the current file. Any errors?

Comment: The problem in more detail is this...when the app deploys, my home page is there with no styling and none of the links work. I have rearranged the ordering of things in the config files several ways but nothing seems to help get the app to see the stylings and javascript.